# Why can't we use due to in 'The picnic was cancelled due to the rain.'?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

I obtained the following sentences at this website https://www.esl-lounge.com/first-certificate/first-certificate-key-word-transformations-27-ans.php.

> The picnic was cancelled due to the rain.
>
> The picnic **WAS CANCELLED BECAUSE OF THE** rain.

The first sentence is wrong but the second is correct.

Why can't we use 'due to' in the first sentence?

---

Another source (from Magoosh) https://gre.magoosh.com/flashcards/grammar/right-or-wrong/the-picnic-was-canceled-due-to-rain suggests that the first sentence is wrong.

The reason provided by Magoosh is as follows:

> "The picnic was canceled, because of rain" or "Cancellation of the picnic was due to rain" or "The cancellation, due to rain, was a problem for ...." The word "due" is an adjective, a noun modifier. It is allowed to modify a noun, as it does in the second and third structure here. It cannot modify the action of a verb, as the original has. For that, we need "because of," which opens a preposition phrase that can modify verbs.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the first sentence.

Comment: Avoiding use of "due to" to mean "because of" is one of those silly pretend rules that some people try to push even though they clearly don't reflect normal real-world usage over (in this case) the last six hundred years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears not to be wrong as the task is to **rewrite** a sentence, not to **correct the mistakes**. You can use **due to** instead of **because of**.

[CALD definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/due?q=due+to):

> ### due to
>
> because of:
>
> - *A lot of her unhappiness is due to boredom.*
> - *The bus was delayed due to heavy snow.*

Comment: According to magoosh https://gre.magoosh.com/flashcards/grammar/right-or-wrong/the-picnic-was-canceled-due-to-rain, it suggests that the first sentence is wrong.

Comment: I apologise for my opinion based comment, but honestly, I would rather trust four dictionaries that agree with one another (please see [CALD](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/due?q=due+to), [LDOCE](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/due-to), [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/due%20to) and [ODO](https://www.lexico.com/definition/due_to) definitions) rather than one cite saying that **due to** is a strict noun modifier. Moreover, [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams) [sees nothing wrong](https://imgur.com/6mrZlOa) in using *due to* instead of *because of*

Comment: Also Corpus of Contemporary American English ([COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/)) shows prevailation of **cancelled due to** over **cancelled because of** with a result of **81 over 42** (please see images [1](https://imgur.com/ADN33V2) and [2](https://imgur.com/lx2pDLT)).

Comment: And examples from COCA: [3](https://imgur.com/JD14Yhj) and [4](https://imgur.com/Wzk3cEo). Seems like that traditionally **due to** *was* a strict noun modifier, but modern rules seem to tend toward using **due to** and **because of** interchangeably.